# What time during translation/compilation JVM computes the value for a companion object?

Tags: kotlin, oop, compilation, jvm

I’m working with Kotlin 1.9.20 on MacOS

```kotlin
enum class Enum {
    SOME_VALUE;

    companion object {
        private val ENV: String = System.getProperty("ENVIRONMENT")
    }
}
```

I tried to write a test for an enum that includes a companion object, but it consistently fails saying that ENV is null.

I tried to use @BeforeAll in test, to set System property, but it doesn’t help, function still returned null

```kotlin
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BeforeAll
        fun setUp(): Unit {
            System.setProperty(ServerEnv.ENV_PROPERTY, "junit")
        }
    }
```

I suspect that Kotlin evaluates the value for the companion object during the compilation to bytecode, but I haven't found any confirmation of this anywhere including documentation, please help me!

Comment: I can’t see a test that checks whether `ENV` is `null`. Further, it’s not obvious whether `ServerEnv.ENV_PROPERTY` is `"ENVIRONMENT"`. If they are supposed to be the same, why not use the same form consistently? Regarding the initialization time, [this document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#semantic-difference-between-object-expressions-and-declarations) says “*A companion object is initialized when the corresponding class is loaded (resolved) that matches the semantics of a Java static initializer*” but there is no use of the class at all in your posted code.

Comment: I think we'd need some more info here.  At runtime, the first time Enum or its companion is referred to, the JVM will load the Enum class, which (as per Holger's quote) will load the companion class; and _that_ will initialise it and hence its properties.  (It certainly won't be evaluated at compile-time; for one thing, it's likely to be run in a different environment from the one it was compiled under, and so it simply wouldn't make sense to generate an executable with an effectively hard-coded environment!)  (contd…)

Comment: Note that you don't have much control over the order of class loading and initialisation; the only guarantee is that it happens before it's needed.  So if you're trying to set the environment _from within the program_, then there's a big risk of setting it too late.  But that's not what the environment is for: it's a way to let the caller (probably a shell) pass values _into_ the program, not to let parts of the program communicate with each other.  There are far better ways to do the latter.